# Digital Copy of Kato's Paper

Tags: reference-request

Kato's celebrated paper "p-adic Hodge theory and values of zeta functions of modular forms" is published in the bound Asterisque collection "Cohomologies p-adiques et applications arithmétiques. Volume III".

I have a copy of this book, but I'm searching (to no avail) for a digital copy of Kato's paper. This would be nice for at least two reasons:

(1) I wouldn't need to carry the book around if I had a laptop/tablet handy.

(2) I could print out portions of the paper and write notes all over them.

Does anyone know where a digital copy of the paper can be found, or whether there are legal reasons preventing a digital copy from existing?

Comment: What about spamming? I mean scanning.

Comment: try http://www.numdam.org

Comment: @Franz I'm not sure what you're implying with the "spamming" comment. I think this question is quite reasonable for MO, considering both the importance and scarcity of this paper.

Scanning is not really an option since it is a borrowed book and I'm afraid that scanning would do considerable damage to the binding.

@Serge Thanks, but I checked there and they don't have it. It's a hard paper to track down.

Comment: see also here (for bad news): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96257/where-to-find-asterisque-online

Comment: @YangMills  That answers my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't want to scan, why not take pictures of each page with a digital camera?

Comment: There are also wand-style scanners which would allow you to scan the book without damaging the binding. I had decent results doing this for a (short!) tract of Poulet from the 1920s.

Comment: Dear Jeff H, I have a digital copy (of a manuscript version).  I can send it to you if you send me an email (and if I can find it!).  Regards,

Comment: For the record, I voted to close as no longer relevant, given Emerton's offer.

Comment: It is available on M. Masdeu's page [here](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masmat/files/eulersystems/Kato-padic_Hodge_theory_values_of_zeta_functions.pdf).